# Blazor client WASM launch configuration for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor-client-side

Where can I find an example of the .NET Core Launch (Blazor Standalone) launch configuration? And before you refer me to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?tabs=visual-studio-code&view=aspnetcore-3.1#vscode I have already been there. No actual example of the configuration file is present.

Comment: **Same here.** Did exactly what the referred linked article say, still. Both *'.NET Core Launch (Blazor Standalone)'* and *'.NET Core Debug Blazor Web Assembly in Chrome'* are **missing**

Comment: Thank you, happy to know I'm not the only one who is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after revisiting this I now understand. in the launch.json I needed to add a line for `"url": "https://localhost:{PORT}"` and use the first port mentioned in `Properties/launchSettings.json`.

To get the browser to open I added `"browser": "edge"` but it does not automatically open the page so I do still need to manually navigate to the url but I can live with that. If anyone figured out how to get the working feel free to share. My `launch.json` looks like the following:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://localhost:7051",
            "browser": "edge"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this too; Just debug with ".Net Core" should be first choice; should auto generate:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (Blazor Standalone)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Project.UI",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Debug Blazor Web Assembly in Chrome",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "timeout": 30000,
            "url": "https://localhost:5001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Project.UI",
            "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My Blazor project is in "/src/Project.UI"

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Replace `"${workspaceFolder}/src/Project.UI"` with the location of your project

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a build task (task.json) first for the blazor WebAssembly

```
   {
   // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
   // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
      {
         "label": "build",
         "command": "dotnet",
         "type": "process",
         "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorSVgTest.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
         ],
         "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
      },
   ]
}
```

And then create a launch task (launch.json) with debug enabled

```
{
   // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
   // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
      {
         "label": "build",
         "command": "dotnet",
         "type": "process",
         "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorSVgTest.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
         ],
         "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
      },
   ]
}
```